# Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\sf\client\node_modules\@heroku\functions-core\bin\benny-windows.exe ENOENT Code: ENOENT

Tags: salesforce-functions

I am attempting to start a Java-based function from within the desired function folder in VS Code Terminal via the command: `sf run function start`

However, it results in an error:

> Error: spawn C:\Program Files
> (x86)\sf\client\node_modules@heroku\functions-core\bin\benny-windows.exe
> ENOENT
> Code: ENOENT

How can I remedy this?

[image]

Two other things that might help with the issue:

1. The `SFDX: Start Function` command appears to be missing from the command palette. I only see
   `SFDX: Stop Function` in there (See screenshot for
   clarity). Why is that?
2. The error message is indicating that it needs
   `benny-windows.exe` in `bin` folder. No idea what that is or why it is needed. But it doesn't exist at all. I mean, `C:\Program Files (x86)\sf\client\node_modules\@heroku\functions-core\` exists but
   there is neither `bin` folder nor a `benny-windows.exe` inside of it

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Please make sure that you’re running the latest version of Salesforce CLI, you can manually update it by this command. After that it should work
sfdx update

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_update_cli.htm

Comment: Based on which experience are you so confident it solves the problem?